# Avoiding duplication in R

Tags: r, duplicates

I am trying to fit a variety of (truncated) probability distributions to the same very thin set of quantiles. I can do it but it seems to require lots of duplication of the same code. Is there a neater way?

I am using this code by Nadarajah and Kotz to generate the pdf of the truncated distributions:

```
qtrunc <- function(p, spec, a = -Inf, b = Inf, ...)
{
  tt <- p
  G <- get(paste("p", spec, sep = ""), mode = "function")
  Gin <- get(paste("q", spec, sep = ""), mode = "function")
  tt <- Gin(G(a, ...) + p*(G(b, ...) - G(a, ...)), ...)
  return(tt)
}
```

where `spec` can be the name of any untruncated distribution for which code in R exists, and the `...` argument is used to provide the names of the parameters of that untruncated distribution.

To achieve the best fit I need to measure the distance between the given quantiles and those calculated using arbitrary values of the parameters of the distribution. In the case of the gamma distribution, for example, the code is as follows:

```
spec <- "gamma"
fit_gamma <- function(x, l = 0,   h = 20, t1 = 5, t2 = 13){
  ct1 <- qtrunc(p = 1/3, spec, a = l, b = h, shape = x[1],rate = x[2])
  ct2 <- qtrunc(p = 2/3, spec, a = l, b = h, shape = x[1],rate = x[2])
  dist <- vector(mode = "numeric", length = 2) 
  dist[1] <- (t1 - ct1)^2
  dist[2] <- (t2- ct2)^2
  return(sqrt(sum(dist)))
}
```

where `l` is the lower truncation, `h` is the higher and I am given the two tertiles `t1` and `t2`.

Finally, I seek the best fit using `optim`, thus:

```
gamma_fit <- optim(par = c(2, 4), 
                fn = fit_gamma, 
                l = l, 
                h = h,
                t1 = t1,
                t2 = t2,
                method = "L-BFGS-B",
                lower = c(1.01, 1.4)
```

Now suppose I want to do the same thing but fitting a normal distribution instead. The names of the parameters of the normal distribution that I am using in R are `mean` and `sd`.

I can achieve what I want but only by writing a whole new function `fit_normal` that is extremely similar to my `fit_gamma` function but with the new parameter names used in the definition of `ct1` and `ct2`.

The problem of duplication of code becomes very severe because I wish to try fitting a large number of different distributions to my data.

What I want to know is whether there is a way of writing a generic `fit_spec` as it were so that the parameter names do not have to be written out by me.

Comment: Please provide the repetitive code of function `fit_normal` so we can see how exactly it is redundant to function `fit_gamma`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `x` as a named list to create a list of arguments to pass into `qtrunc()` using `do.call()`.

```r
fit_distro <- function(x, spec, l = 0, h = 20, t1 = 5, t2 = 13){
  args <- c(x, list(spec = spec, a = l, b = h))
  
  ct1 <- do.call(qtrunc, args = c(list(p = 1/3), args))
  ct2 <- do.call(qtrunc, args = c(list(p = 2/3), args))
  dist <- vector(mode = "numeric", length = 2) 
  dist[1] <- (t1 - ct1)^2
  dist[2] <- (t2 - ct2)^2
  return(sqrt(sum(dist)))
}
```

This is called as follows, which is the same as your original function.

```r
fit_distro(list(shape = 2, rate = 3), "gamma")
# [1] 13.07425

fit_gamma(c(2, 3))
# [1] 13.07425
```

This will work with other distributions, for however many parameters they have.

```r
fit_distro(list(mean = 10, sd = 3), "norm")
# [1] 4.08379

fit_distro(list(shape1 = 2, shape2 = 3, ncp = 10), "beta")
# [1] 12.98371
```

Comment: Many thanks, Adam. I have never got `do.call` in my working mental tool kit.